# Scope issue: storing account credentials in a new class object within a promise, but now need to use this object in the rest of the class

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, scope, google-cloud-firestore

I have successfully retrieved data from Firebase to set as the client id and client secret. To do this, I had to use a promise.then in order to ensure that the credentials that are being set occur after the data is retrieved.

```
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
admin.firestore().collection('credentials').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_id));
        // Credentials.client_id = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_id);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_secret));
        // Credentials.client_secret = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_secret);
        let client_id = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_id);
        let client_secret = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_secret);
        const credentials = new Credentials(regexIdAndSecret(client_id), regexIdAndSecret(client_secret));




        const Spotify = new SpotifyWebApi({
            client_id: credentials.client_id,
            client_secret: credentials.client_secret,
            redirectUri: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseapp.com/popup.html`
        });
        console.log('This is the client id after it has been set ' + credentials.client_id);
        console.log('This is the client secret after it has been set ' + credentials.client_secret);

    });


});
```

However, I now have the predicament that I need to be using the 'Spotify' throughout the rest of my code. Because it is inside this promise, the scope of it is limited only to inside the promise. How can I set the credentials with the correctly retrieved Firebase data so that the 'Spotify' object works for the whole class?

Example of another place I use the Spotify object below (but is not working now since Spotify is no longer a class object:

```
/**
 * Redirects the User to the Spotify authentication consent screen. Also the 'state' cookie is set for later state
 * verification.
 */
exports.redirect = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    cookieParser()(req, res, () => {

        const state = req.cookies.state || crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
        console.log('Setting verification state:', state);
        res.cookie('state', state.toString(), {maxAge: 3600000, secure: true, httpOnly: true});
        const authorizeURL = Spotify.createAuthorizeURL(OAUTH_SCOPES, state.toString());
        res.redirect(authorizeURL);
    });
});
```

Entire file:

```
/**
 * Main class holding all the logic which matches the Google assistant application to the Firebase database
 * and the Spotify dashboard application. The application is formatted to reflect these three main parts with
 * response-requests to Spotify for authorisation and to make api function calls (within the dialogflow fulfillment
 * code towards the bottom of the class).
 * Author: Marcus Watts
 * Date Created: 01 July 2019
 */
'use strict';


/**
 * --------------------------- Google/Dialogflow/Firebase Setup ---------------------------
 * @type {{analytics; auth; crashlytics; database; firestore; https; pubsub; remoteConfig; storage; testLab; app: apps.Apps; Event: Event; EventContext: EventContext; Change: Change; ChangeJson: ChangeJson; Resource: Resource; TriggerAnnotated: TriggerAnnotated; Runnable: Runnable; HttpsFunction: HttpsFunction; CloudFunction: CloudFunction; MakeCloudFunctionArgs: MakeCloudFunctionArgs; makeCloudFunction; optionsToTrigger; config; firebaseConfig; region; runWith; FunctionBuilder: FunctionBuilder; SUPPORTED_REGIONS: readonly; MIN_TIMEOUT_SECONDS: number; MAX_TIMEOUT_SECONDS: number; VALID_MEMORY_OPTIONS: readonly; ScheduleRetryConfig: ScheduleRetryConfig; Schedule: Schedule; RuntimeOptions: RuntimeOptions; DeploymentOptions: DeploymentOptions}}
 */

//  Modules being used
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// Sets this file as the webhook for dialogflow filfillment
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
// Used for storing the sign in data of the Spotify user
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const crypto = require('crypto');

// Firebase Setup
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./service-account.json');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseio.com`
});

// async function getCredentials() {
//     const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('credentials').get();
//     return snapshot;
// }
//


class Credentials {

    constructor(client_id, client_secret) {
        this.client_id = client_id;
        console.log('Id in class ' + this.client_id);
        this.client_secret = client_secret;
        console.log('Secret in class ' + this.client_secret);

    }


}

/**
 * ----------------------Below section of code found at: LINK TO GIT REPOSTITORY---------------------------------
 */

function regexIdAndSecret(clientIdOrSecret){
    const regex = /[(\w)]+/g;
    let n;
    let match;
    while ((n = regex.exec(clientIdOrSecret)) !== null) {
        // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
        if (n.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }

        // The result can be accessed through the `n`-variable.
        n.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
            return match;
            console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);

        });
        console.log(`Found n,  ${n}`);
        return n;
    }

}


// Spotify OAuth 2 setup
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
admin.firestore().collection('credentials').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_id));
        // Credentials.client_id = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_id);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_secret));
        // Credentials.client_secret = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_secret);
        let client_id = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_id);
        let client_secret = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_secret);
        const credentials = new Credentials(regexIdAndSecret(client_id), regexIdAndSecret(client_secret));




        const Spotify = new SpotifyWebApi({
            client_id: credentials.client_id,
            client_secret: credentials.client_secret,
            redirectUri: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseapp.com/popup.html`
        });
        console.log('This is the client id after it has been set ' + credentials.client_id);
        console.log('This is the client secret after it has been set ' + credentials.client_secret);

    });

// Scopes to request. (Added in all the possible scopes for the auth so that it is possible to do any action that the
// Spotify api will allow i.e maximum permissions granted)
const OAUTH_SCOPES = [
    'user-read-email',
    'app-remote-control',
    'streaming',
    'user-modify-playback-state',
    'playlist-read-private',
    'user-library-modify',
    'playlist-read-collaborative',
    'playlist-modify-private',
    'user-follow-modify',
    'user-read-currently-playing',
    'user-read-email',
    'user-library-read',
    'user-top-read',
    'playlist-modify-public',
    'user-follow-read',
    'user-read-playback-state',
    'user-read-recently-played'
];

/**
 * Redirects the User to the Spotify authentication consent screen. Also the 'state' cookie is set for later state
 * verification.
 */
exports.redirect = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    cookieParser()(req, res, () => {

        const state = req.cookies.state || crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
        console.log('Setting verification state:', state);
        res.cookie('state', state.toString(), {maxAge: 3600000, secure: true, httpOnly: true});
        const authorizeURL = Spotify.createAuthorizeURL(OAUTH_SCOPES, state.toString());
        res.redirect(authorizeURL);
    });
});


/**
 * Exchanges a given Spotify auth code passed in the 'code' URL query parameter for a Firebase auth token.
 * The request also needs to specify a 'state' query parameter which will be checked against the 'state' cookie.
 * The Firebase custom auth token is sent back in a JSONP callback function with function name defined by the
 * 'callback' query parameter.
 */
exports.token = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    try {
        cookieParser()(req, res, () => {
            console.log('Received verification state:', req.cookies.state);
            console.log('Received state:', req.query.state);
            if (!req.cookies.state) {
                throw new Error(
                    'State cookie not set or expired. Maybe you took too long to authorize. Please try again.'
                );
            } else if (req.cookies.state !== req.query.state) {
                throw new Error('State validation failed');
            }
            console.log('Received auth code:', req.query.code);
            Spotify.authorizationCodeGrant(req.query.code, (error, data) => {
                if (error) {
                    throw error;
                }
                /**
                 * Store the codes retained from the Authorization. (Added in the refresh token so that it can be used and set as appropriate to ensure
                 * the user is constantly connected to the Spotify api)
                 */
                console.log('Received Access Token:', data.body['access_token']);
                console.log('Received Refresh Token:', data.body['refresh_token']);
                Spotify.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token']);
                Spotify.setRefreshToken(data.body['refresh_token']);
                // setterForRefreshToken(data.body['refresh_token']);
                Spotify.getMe(async (error, userResults) => {
                    if (error) {
                        throw error;
                    }
                    console.log('Auth code exchange result received:', userResults);
                    // We have a Spotify access token and the user identity now.
                    const accessToken = data.body['access_token'];
                    const spotifyUserID = userResults.body['id'];
                    const profilePic = userResults.body['images'][0]['url'];
                    const userName = userResults.body['display_name'];
                    const email = userResults.body['email'];

                    // Create a Firebase account and get the Custom Auth Token.
                    const firebaseToken = await createFirebaseAccount(
                        spotifyUserID,
                        userName,
                        profilePic,
                        email,
                        accessToken
                    );
                    // Serve an HTML page that signs the user in and updates the user profile.
                    res.jsonp({token: firebaseToken});
                });
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return res.jsonp({error: error.toString});
    }
    return null;
});

/**
 * Creates a Firebase account with the given user profile and returns a custom auth token allowing
 * signing-in this account.
 * Also saves the accessToken to the datastore at /spotifyAccessToken/$uid
 *
 * @returns {Promise<string>} The Firebase custom auth token in a promise.
 */
async function createFirebaseAccount(spotifyID, displayName, photoURL, email, accessToken) {
    // The UID we'll assign to the user.
    const uid = `spotify:${spotifyID}`;

    // Save the access token to the Firebase Realtime Database.
    const databaseTask = admin.database().ref(`/spotifyAccessToken/${uid}`).set(accessToken);

    // Create or update the user account.
    const userCreationTask = admin
        .auth()
        .updateUser(uid, {
            displayName: displayName,
            photoURL: photoURL,
            email: email,
            emailVerified: true
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // If user does not exists we create it.
            if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
                return admin.auth().createUser({
                    uid: uid,
                    displayName: displayName,
                    photoURL: photoURL,
                    email: email,
                    emailVerified: true
                });
            }
            throw error;
        });

    // Wait for all async tasks to complete, then generate and return a custom auth token.
    await Promise.all([userCreationTask, databaseTask]);
    // Create a Firebase custom auth token.
    const token = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid);
    console.log('Created Custom token for UID "', uid, '" Token:', token);
    return token;
}

/**
 * ----------------- Classes for storing the refresh and access tokens which are attained at sign in:-----------------
 * used to create instance variables which can be accessible anywhere within the class
 */

class Refresh {
    // Instance variables store the refresh token
    constructor(refresh_token) {
        this.refresh_token = refresh_token;
    }
}

// Instance variables store the refresh token
class Access {
    constructor(accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }
}


/**
 * ---------------------------Setter and Getter Functions for Spotify Auth URL--------------------------------
 */

function setterForUpdatedAccessToken(splitString) {
    Access.accessToken = splitString;
    console.log('This is the access token being set in setterForUpdatedAccessToken', Access.accessToken);
}

function getterForUpdatedAccessToken() {
    console.log('This is the access token being get in getterForUpdatedAccessToken', Access.accessToken);
    return JSON.stringify(Access.accessToken);
}
```

Update: getting error Cannopt read property 'createAuthorizeURL' of undefined at spotify.then.Spotify

```
const spotify = admin.firestore().collection('credentials').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_id));
        // Credentials.client_id = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_id);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_secret));
        // Credentials.client_secret = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_secret);
        let client_id = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_id);
        let client_secret = JSON.stringify(doc.data().client_secret);
        const credentials = new Credentials(regexIdAndSecret(client_id), regexIdAndSecret(client_secret));


        const Spotify = new SpotifyWebApi({
            client_id: credentials.client_id,
            client_secret: credentials.client_secret,
            redirectUri: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseapp.com/popup.html`
        });
        console.log('This is the client id after it has been set ' + credentials.client_id);
        console.log('This is the client secret after it has been set ' + credentials.client_secret);
        return Spotify;
    });



});

exports.redirect = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    cookieParser()(req, res, () => {

        const state = req.cookies.state || crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
        console.log('Setting verification state:', state);
        res.cookie('state', state.toString(), {maxAge: 3600000, secure: true, httpOnly: true});
        spotify.then(Spotify => {
            const authorizeURL = Spotify.createAuthorizeURL(OAUTH_SCOPES, state.toString());
            res.redirect(authorizeURL);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the code in your first code block part (this line: `admin.firestore().collection('credentials').get()`) of a class method? If so, could you add the declaration?

Comment: I'm new to Javascript so I'm not sure exactly what a class method is. The following code: const admin = require('firebase-admin'); is taken from the Firebase CLI library. So the admin.firestore code you mentioned is accessing the firestore collection database. Not sure if this answers your question?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by add the declaration please?

Comment: You stated your question as: `How can I set the credentials with the correctly retrieved Firebase data so that the 'Spotify' object works for the whole class?`; if possible, please show us what that class is.

Comment: Sorry for my noobishness! const Spotify = new SpotifyWebApi({
            client_id: credentials.client_id,
            client_secret: credentials.client_secret,
            redirectUri: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseapp.com/popup.html`
        }); This is the Spotify object. It runs off the Spotify Web Api Node wrapper found here https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node -> go down to usage to see how it is instantiated.

Comment: I will edit my whole class file inside the question if that helps

Comment: I believe I understand your point now. As you can see there is no entire class which everything fits under in my index.js file. Should I put everything inside a class?

Comment: You just want to use your `Spotify` right? Just declare it outside the `const SpotifyWebApi` and then populate it with `this.Spotify`. But I would change the name to `spotify` since you don`t use it as a class.

Comment: In your code you do `snapshot.docs.forEach`, and instantiate several `Spotify` instances with different credentials. Why is that?

Comment: There is only one set of credentials on my firestore database. Is there a way to access only one doc? I could only see online people using the .forEach method. Perhaps this is what is causing the undefined error

Comment: Although I don't have any access to the Spotify node wrapper methods in the redirect function (or anywhere else outside that admin.firestore().collection promise). You should be able to write Spotify.getClientId but this is not available. So for some reason, the storing of the Spotify const into the spotify const is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the spotify class instance from your `.then` callback and store the promise somewhere accessible to all your other code. E.g. at the top of the file or in a separate module:

```
// spotify.js
module.exports = admin.firestore().collection('credentials').get().then((snapshot) => {
  /*...*/
  return Spotify;
});
```

Anywhere else in your code you can do

```
const spotify = require('./spotify');
// ...
spotify.then(Spotify => {
  // do stuff with Spotify
});
```

And of course if you are inside an async function, you could just use `await` (but then I'd choose different variable names):

```
const Spotify = await spotify;
// do stuff with Spotify
```

For example:

```
const spotify = require('./spotify');
// ...
exports.redirect = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    cookieParser()(req, res, () => {

        const state = req.cookies.state || crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
        console.log('Setting verification state:', state);
        res.cookie('state', state.toString(), {maxAge: 3600000, secure: true, httpOnly: true});
        spotify.then(Spotify => {
            const authorizeURL = Spotify.createAuthorizeURL(OAUTH_SCOPES, state.toString());
            res.redirect(authorizeURL);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am getting an undefined error for the spotify.then.Spotify (see above update). Have I missed something?

Comment: You have the `return Spotify` statement inside a `forEach`  loop. That can’t work. I don’t know why you have to authorize with Spotify multiple times. Are the user credentials really different for every item in the array? If so, how would you know which credentials to use in your redirect routine? In other words, you are creating multiple spotify objects but later want to use only one. This is the error in your logic. I can’t really help you here since I don’t know anything else about your application.

Comment: Thank you Felix, I used your advice and changed it to having spotify inside another js file and to require it from the main index.js file. I also changed it to just read one particular account credential. The only reason it has taken meekest so long to respond is because, when requiring the spotify credentials from the other js file, my second method - exports.token doesn't work. I have started from scratch to test this, and the auth code which the cookie parser receives fails only when requiring spotify from elsewhere. I will make another question about this but any info would be appreciated!